# SQL query to extract field values from rows sharing same value in specific column, and combine those value into a single row

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla, joomfish

I am trying to export translated content from Joomla's Joomfish MySQL database table.

The way Joomfish works is by translating fields separately and storing them in a jos_jf_content table with a reference id to the original source content from jos_content table.  For example, one row may hold the translated title, another row the translated categories, and another the fulltext content. These rows are separate and only share the reference_id value.

So one has a jos_jf_content table where the columns of interest are:

reference_id (id of source) | reference_field (title|fulltext|metadesc) | value (translation)

I need to combine all the values sharing the same reference_id into a single row whose columns are Title, Fulltext, Metadesc etc .

Any hint?

UPDATE:

Original table is like:

```
|reference_id|   reference_field |   value        |

        10          title               A title
        10          fulltext           Body of post
```

I need to export it (CSV etc) as:

```
|  ID    |  TITLE    |    FULLTEXT     | 

|  10    |   A Title |  Body of post  |
```

Comment: I believe this will help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283541/merging-multiple-rows-into-one-row-and-multiple-columns-on-mysql

Comment: Thank you that did the job after a litttle tuning.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Mysql GROUP_CONCAT() so your query might look like

```
SELECT group_concat(column_name) FROM table where reference_id = 'rid'
```

assuming the column name used to save these information is same.
if not please paste your table structure. if they stored in different columns you can use concat too.

Comment: Thank you , however I am not trying to concatenate values into a string, but to reassemble values from different rows (which have in common only a reference_id) into a new database row such as | ID | Title | Fulltext | Metadesc |

Comment: Can you post your table structure of how the values are currently and how you would like it to be. this will make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

I think then the following query fits the objective. Thanks to Bill Purchase for the link to a similar situation. (note I ended up needing the introtext only instead of the fulltext)

```
    SELECT DISTINCT jf.reference_id
   , t.value AS title
   , it.value AS introtext
   , mk.value AS metakey
   , md.value AS metadesc
FROM jos_jf_content AS jf
LEFT JOIN jos_jf_content AS t ON jf.reference_id = t.reference_id
  AND t.reference_field = 'title' AND t.reference_table='content'
LEFT JOIN jos_jf_content AS it ON jf.reference_id = it.reference_id
  AND it.reference_field = 'introtext' AND it.reference_table='content'
LEFT JOIN jos_jf_content AS mk ON jf.reference_id = mk.reference_id
  AND mk.reference_field = 'metakey' AND mk.reference_table='content'
LEFT JOIN jos_jf_content AS md ON jf.reference_id = md.reference_id
  AND md.reference_field = 'metadesc' AND md.reference_table='content'
WHERE jf.reference_table='content'
ORDER BY jf.reference_id
```