# MySQL query for getting Joomla users and their profile fields

Tags: mysql, joomla

I am creating a user profile plugin in Joomla 2.5 to extend the standard user fields.

The issue is I need an efficient way to retrieve the users (along with the extra fields) via a MySQL query. Currently the best method I can think of is querying the #__user_profiles table and processing that data to determine the extra fields to load and then producing a query that creates a separate join on the #__user_profiles table for each extra user field.

Obviously that isn't very efficient and on a large user base the query is quite slow.

Is there a better way to combine extra user fields that are separate records in another table into one query?

EDIT:

I have an external script that needs to grab all the users and their extended fields so I need to combine the #_*users and #*_user_profiles tables

Comment: How is your extension table defined?

Comment: Have you tried the default joomla, User-Profile plugin for extending the standard user field

Comment: @OlafDietsche I am using the standard #__users and #__user_profiles tables.

Comment: @Tornado my plugin is modelled on the standard user-profile plugin. But my issue is that I have an external script that needs to grab all the users and their extended fields and I was wondering if there is an efficient way to combine the #__users and #__user_profiles tables.

Comment: How many users do you have? From my point of view, if you need to get it all in one step, a join between the two tables is the fastest way to go.

Comment: @ValentinDespa on one site I have over 100,000. I am currently performing a query like the one described in the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283541/merging-multiple-rows-into-one-row-and-multiple-columns-on-mysql . I was hoping there might be a more efficient way.

Comment: Why is it that you aren't just using the standard Joomla JFactory::getUser api for this?

Comment: Let me add to my comment that you can of course just fire up the Joomla platform with the standard jFactory::getUser api from inside your application if that's what you need.

Comment: @Elin I'm using the Joomla Platform in the external script unfortunately JFactory:getUser is only helpful for retrieving an individual user. My script needs to process 10's of thousands (to send off to MailChimp) so looping through and calling getUser for each user is a fairly expensive way to do it, I would prefer to get all the data  up front and in one query.

Comment: Well if you look at how profile does it you might be able to adapt it. it uses the api to loadRowList which gives you an array of profile fields 
'SELECT profile_key, profile_value FROM #__user_profiles' .
     ' WHERE user_id = '.(int) $userId." AND profile_key LIKE 'profile.%'" .
     ' ORDER BY ordering'  ... that might help.

Comment: @Elin this is great when retrieving a single user but isn't really suitable for multiple users. I have decided to go for a pivot table approach, I have added an example in an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I decided to go for a pivot table approach

example:

```
SELECT
    #__users.*,
    MAX(CASE WHEN profile_key = "example.firstname" THEN profile_value END) AS FirstName,
    MAX(CASE WHEN profile_key = "example.lastname" THEN profile_value END) AS LastName,
    MAX(CASE WHEN profile_key = "example.company" THEN profile_value END) AS Company
FROM #__users LEFT JOIN #__user_profiles ON #__users.id = #__user_profiles.user_id
GROUP BY #__users.id
```

This allows me to have all the extra user data in one row so I can easily order and filter.

Answer (score 4):

This is simply a join between the two tables

```
select u.*, p.*
from #__users u
left join #__user_profiles p on p.user_id = u.id
```

This retrieves all user and associated profile entries.
Depending on what rows or profile entries you really need, you can restrict this query with an additional where clause.

If you want the user and associated profile entries in one row, you can combine the profile entries with `group_concat`

```
select u.*, group_concat(p.profile_key, '=', p.profile_value)
from #__users u
left join #__user_profiles p on p.user_id = u.id
group by u.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @OlafDietsche, I think the first query would be fine for a small/medium number of users with a small amount of extra fields. Unfortunately I'm dealing with 100,000+ users with 20+ extra fields. I like the second query but since the group_concat creates a single field it limits my filtering and ordering options. I have decided to go for a pivot table approach, I have added an example in an answer above.